# ubuntu enable specific php extension

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have just upgraded to ubuntu 16.04. Now I have in `/etc` a folder for php5.6, one for 7.0 and one for 7.1 each with their `mods-available` subfolder.

I have installed the php7.0-zip extension and I see it in the `mods-available` subfolder for php7.0.

How to enable it? `phpenmod` will look in 5.6 version `mods-available` only...

Comment: it depends on where you are going to use it, there are extensions for php-cli, php-fpm and so on

Comment: I am using it in php-cli mode.

Comment: and what does `php7.0-cli -m` say? (I can confuse commands a bit in favor of usual `php-cli -m` for php5, but it has to show modules you have currently loaded for your cli side)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `phpenmod -v 7.0 extension`?

Alternatively, you can create the symlink yourself (which is what phpenmod does internally):

```
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/extension.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/extension.ini
```

Comment: +1 for just creating the link yourself.  Don't forget to restart Apache so it re-reads config, etc.